# Dynamically fetch object using Unity C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, unity-container

I need a way by which I can fetch concrete instances via Unity at runtime, based on a request parameter in my controller or a request filter.

I've added these 2 lines in my Global.asax.cs:

```
container.RegisterType<IAlphabet, English>("english");
container.RegisterType<IAlphabet, Russian>("russian");
```

Now how do I fetch the accurate instance in my `ActionFilter` when I'm getting a request variable `lang` in my request param? I'm not able to get the current `container` instance in my RequestFilter.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660794(v=pandp.30)) method:

```
var lang = "english";
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IAlphabet, English>("english");
container.RegisterType<IAlphabet, Russian>("russian");

IAlphabet rus = container.Resolve<IAlphabet>();  // returns the Russian object
IAlphabet eng = container.Resolve<IAlphabet>(lang); // returns the English object
```

Comment: I'm not able to fetch the container instance in my Filter class to which I registered the types in Global.asax.cs

Comment: Ok you've effectively changed the question. I'd create a factory singleton and inject the container instance into that and then inject the factory into your request filter spinning up your alphabet instance that way.